# Formula Field and pick list

Tags: apex, code

```
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Employee_Title__c ,'Software Engineer'),50000,
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Employee_Title__c ,'Senior Software Engineer'),70000,
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Employee_Title__c , 'Team Lead'),90000,
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL( Employee_Title__c , 'Manager') , 100000,
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL( Employee_Title__c , 'Solution Manager'),110000,
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(Employee_Title__c ,'Technical Solution Manager'),120000,0))))))
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! I see a formula, but I do not see a question. Please edit your post to add exactly what you are trying to accomplish, and what is your issue: if an error, add *exact* error text; if unexpected results, give details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear with the Question, However, based on your formula **My Understanding is based on Picklist i.e Employee we need to assign salary.**

If that is Usecase then use below formula field

```
Case(Employee_Title__c ,
    'Software Engineer',50000,
    'Senior Software Engineer',70000,
    'Team Lead',90000,
    'Manager' , 100000,
    'Solution Manager',110000,
    'Technical Solution Manager',120000,
    0)
```

*https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&type=5*